# I can't catch action in new intent

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I am building my `Bot` on the `Facebook` platform, my code is pushed to the `Heroku` platform and from there the `Bot` will react to what I have programmed. However, recently I want to add a new `intent` to my `Agent` and write code to record `action` in the intent, and the strange thing is that the `Bot` **doesn't recognize this new `intent`**, but when I try with `actions` was there before, the bot responded correctly.

I don't know if there is a new `Dialogflow` policy that I am missing?
[MyCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IIka.png)

Comment: To sum up, your action code is working but you are not able to add new intent to your agent. Did you use example from [Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/how/manage-intents#create_intent) ? Which programming language you are using? Please share your code inside your question, not adding it as a screen, it will be more visible. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Did you train the Dialogflow model after adding the new intent?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I added a new intent to my agent and it did not get recognized. Later I found that it was a language problem. In my code I used the language 'en-US' for my Dialogflow agent, but I added the new intent in the 'en' section.

So, you just need to add your intent in the language you're actually using in your website or application.